# Confusion about pointer to fixed array

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

Consider following example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct test_t {
    char (*p)[20];
} test;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    test t;

    t.p = malloc(2 * sizeof(*t.p));

    strcpy(t.p[0], "hello");

    strcpy(t.p[1], "world");

    printf("[%s]\n", t.p[0]);
    printf("[%s]\n", t.p[1]);

    free(t.p);
}
```

The above code is incorrect as the `malloc` is not allocating enough memory for the element with index 1. This can be seen when running it under valgrind. When I double the amount of malloced memory from:

```
t.p = malloc(2 * sizeof(char *));
```

to:

```
t.p = malloc(4 * sizeof(char *));
```

the valgrind output no longer shows memory errors.

I understand the reason for the errors however I cannot see how I should be calculating the required memory for the malloc call.

Thanks.

EDITED: The example code

Comment: `2 * sizeof(char *)` on 64BIT means `16` and `4 * sizeof(char *)` means `32`

Comment: `test t; memset(&t, 0, sizeof(test));` - Better use an initialiser: `test t = { NULL };` `memset` is not guaranteed to set the pointer to a _null pointer_. In general don't use `memset` explicitly (the compiler might generate code which calls it behind the scenes) if there are better (e.g. type-safe) or equivalent alternatives.

Comment: @Michi Yes, but why 4 if I want allocate only 2 elements?

Comment: @Caspinol: Get the types right! `p` is a pointer to an array. This is typically used to point to a 2D array's first row (and column).

Comment: @Caspinol Why would you allocate only 2 elements? Your `p` is a pointer to _20_ elements. Allocating anything other than 20 chars is just asking for trouble.

Comment: @Caspinol you nead `t.p = malloc(26);`. Now try to think Why.

Comment: @Olaf Thanks, didn't know i could do that.

Comment: First check if you can do it type-safe before using hacks. Oh, and general advice: enable all relevant warnings and pay heed to them.

Comment: @zenith Because the 20 "columns" is static, the dynamic part are the "rows". And i need 2 of them for this example

Comment: @Olaf Where is the hack here. This is a valid pointer to a array of 20 chars.

Comment: All your uses of `memcpy` are actually hacks. There are better, easier and safer ways for each of them. For the first I already commented what's hackish about it. For the others, every C book can tell you. No offence, but your code is shooting through the knee in the head. But maybe you just should see [ask].

Comment: @Olaf Ok, thats fine. Noted. But the problem here are the pointers ;)

Comment: @Caspinol: Yes. And you would have seen if you would not have silenced compiler warnings with that `memcpy` hacks! Done the proper way, the compiler will complain about type miss matches. I'm done. Just please **learn** from your faults!

Comment: You should use `strcpy` instead of `memcpy`, since you're dealing with null terminated strings.

Comment: @Olaf Did you try yourself? gcc main.c -g -Wall -o test produces no warnings for the above code.

Comment: Sure it does not! Because you actively tell your compiler not to help you by using functions which use the "universal" pointer `void *`, so it **cannot** warn. Go learn before offending people who just want to help you. Also recommended warnings include `-Wextra -Wshadow` and `-Wpedantic` for strict standard compliance.

Comment: @Olaf Still no warning with those options except the one about arguments to main. So yeah the whole reason i asked the question was for me to learn something...about what i asked. But at this stage lets just go separate ways M'Kay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`t.p` is a pointer to an array of arrays of 20 `char`: you access 2 such arrays in your program, hence you should allocate 40 bytes for these.

There is an easier way to do this: allocate the size of the object `p` points to times the number of elements in the array:

```
t.p = malloc(sizeof(*t.p) * 2);
```

This way if you change the definition of `struct test_t`, the amount allocated by `malloc` with adjust automatically.

Note that your statements are redundant:

```
memset(&t, 0, sizeof(test));
```

can be simplified as `test t = { NULL };`, or `t.p = NULL;`, or even completely elided since `malloc` will set the value of `t.p`.

```
strcpy(t.p[0], "hello");
t.p[0][strlen("hello")] = '\0';  // useless: the '\0' was alread set there by strcpy

strcpy(t.p[1], "world");
t.p[1][strlen("world")] = '\0';  // useless: the '\0' was alread set there by strcpy
```

The whole code can be simplified as:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct test_t {
    char (*p)[20];
} test;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    test t;

    t.p = malloc(sizeof(*t.p) * 2);

    strcpy(t.p[0], "hello");
    strcpy(t.p[1], "world");

    printf("[%s]\n", t.p[0]);
    printf("[%s]\n", t.p[1]);

    free(t.p);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks for that and the code pointers. The comments under the question almost ripped my head off ;) Initially i used memcpy in the example. So cheers for the answer it works.